# Setting apache2 as default web server on ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx

So on my ubuntu server I have both apache2 and nginx installed for testing purposes. However, currently nginx is set as default (nginx is the one that starts up when the server is restarted), but I need apache2 to be the default (apache2 starts when the server is restarted).

What configuration do  I need to change to make that happen?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by default? Is it the server that actually starts and "get the ports" ?

Comment: by "default" yes I suppose that would be correct. The solution would be either a way to stop nginx from running at start up, or start apache2 before nginx so apache2 gets the port and nginx fails to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What may be happening is that the Apache 2 init script has higher priority than the Nginx script.

You can either change the priorities (but then the lower priority server may not "get its ports"), or just change the init scripts that get run.

Change the priority with:

```
update-rc.d nginx defaults
update-rc.d apache2 start 30 2 3 4 5 . stop 70 0 1 6
```

Just enable Nginx with:

```
update-rc.d nginx defaults
update-rc.d apache2 disable
```

More options and syntax detail in the update-rc.d manual page.